# How do I use Sinatra to serve XML documents?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have some XML documents that I'd like to server from Sinatra. I did some searching but couldn't find anything specific. 
I did find the builder gem but I don't want to build the document from scratch.

I tried to do something like this

```
get '/'
  xml = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <name>My name</name> <age>90</age>'
  body xml
end
```

but that will add the HTML tags around it. It's probably something really basic I'm missing. Can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: What is your expected output of get '/' xml = "My name 90" body xml?

Comment: the post is wrapping the xml tags. It's something like this

Comment: <name> "name" </name> <age>"90"</age>

Answer (score 38):

This is very simple with Sinatra:

```
get '/' do
  content_type 'text/xml'
  "<name>Luis</name><age>99</age>"
end
```

On get '/' the response will be the XML `"<name>Luis</name><age>99</age>"` with the correct content_type.

Comment: I knew it was something simple... Should've thought of that!

Comment: I wish I could accept answers on behalf of askers after a few years.

Comment: This answer is no completely right and have an exception on the Sinatra level. XML should have only one root element: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

Answer (score 2):

As answered below, in addition Wagner's answer of adding the content type, you must include only one XML root element http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp otherwise Sinatra will raise an exception.

So the complete answer is:

```
get '/'
  content_type 'text/xml'
  '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root><name>My name</name> <zage>90</age></root>'
end
```